# Recursion in Django View

Tags: python, django, recursion

I'm making a minesweeper game and I want to use a recursive function to reveal many tiles when I click a blank tile.

So far I have this in my views.py:

```
def reveal(board_id, x, y):
        tile = Tile.objects.filter(board=board_id, x=x, y=y)
    if tile[0].revealed == False:
        tile.update(revealed=True)
        if tile[0].mine == False and tile[0].value == 0:
            if x != 0:
                tempx = x-1
                reveal(board_id, tempx, y)
            if x != 9:
                tempx = x+1
                reveal(board_id, tempx, y)
            if y != 0:
                tempy = y-1
                reveal(board_id, x, tempy)
            if y != 9:
                tempy = y+1
                reveal(board_id, x, tempy)
```

It gives me a server error.

Comment: @colinglass Can you give any more details about the error thrown?

Comment: What's the server error and traceback exactly?

Comment: Hmm as I am new to python I don't know how to get the traceback but this is what reads in the log: ```[22/Mar/2014 20:42:41] "POST /game/13/ HTTP/1.1" 500 9986```

Comment: Completely unrelated to the problem, but I just want to mention that this function probably shouldn't be in `views.py`. I'd make it a method on `Tile`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The x and y values were being passed as unicode character so it was throwing an exception when I tried to add or subtract these values.

Basically,

```
x = int(x)
y = int(y)
```

Solved it for me.

Answer (score 1):

My guess it that `reveal()` keeps walking over already revealed Tiles.

```
if not tile[0].revealed and tile[0].mine == False and tile[0].value == 0:
    ....
```

Comment: Hmm.. no this isn't it. But I did put a safeguard at the beginning thanks to you bringing this up, will update my code

Comment: Looks like this should not run at all because `tile[0]` undefined at the beginning of the function as you pasted it.